# How to Retrieve the EditText Values from conditional statements

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I'm unable to retrieve the data in the code. If user enters a number within the range as mentioned in the `if else` statements, it should return back the integer value.

Example: If I enter 46 in `et1`, then I should get 6 in `n1` on pressing the button `bt1`.

`parseInt()` only retrieves the entered values, please help, Thank You.

```java
public class mt11 extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText et1, et2;
    private Button bt1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mt11);

        et1 = findViewById(R.id.mt1011);
       // et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mt1012);

        bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mt1sgpa1);

        bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                int num = 0;
                int S = 10, A = 9, B = 8, C = 7, D = 6, E = 4, F =0;

                if (num >= 0 && num <= 41) {
                    num = F ;
                }
                else if (num >= 42 && num <= 44) {
                    num = E;
                }
                else if (num >= 45 && num <= 59) {
                    num = D;
                }
                else if (num >= 60 && num <= 69) {
                    num = C;
                }
                else if (num >= 70 && num <= 79) {
                    num = B;
                }
                else if (num >= 80 && num <= 89) {
                    num = A;
                }
                else {
                    num = S;
                }



                int n1 = Integer.valueOf(et1.getText().charAt(num));
               // int n2 = Integer.parseInt(et2.getText().toString());

                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mt11.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("New Semester");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Your Grade is : " + String.valueOf(n1));
                        //Showing Alert Message
                        alertDialog.show();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can create as a method and call where ever you want as follows.**

public class mt11 extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private EditText et1, et2;
private Button bt1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mt11);

    et1 = findViewById(R.id.mt1011);
   // et2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.mt1012);

    bt1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mt1sgpa1);

    bt1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        showGrade(calculateGrage(et1.getText().toString()));
        }
    });
}

private String calculateGrage(String range) {
    int S = 10, A = 9, B = 8, C = 7, D = 6, E = 4, F =0;
    int num = 0, result = 0;
    try {
        num = Integer.parseInt(range);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        //Not in correct format
    }
   if(num == 0 || num < 0) {
     result = F;
   } else {
       if (num <= 41) {
           result = F;
       } else if (num <= 44) {
           result = E;
       } else if (num <= 59) {
           result = D;
       } else if (num <= 69) {
           result = C;
       } else if (num <= 79) {
           result = B;
       } else if (num <= 89) {
           result = A;
       } else {
           result = S;
       }
   }
    return String.valueOf(result);
}

private void showGrade(String grade) {
    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
    alertDialog.setTitle("New Semester");
    alertDialog.setMessage("Your Grade is : " + grade);
    //Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to this:

```
int num = 0;
try {
    num = Integer.parseInt(et1.getText().toString());
} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
    //Not in correct format
}

int grade = 0;
int S = 10, A = 9, B = 8, C = 7, D = 6, E = 4, F =0;

if (num >= 0 && num <= 41) {
    grade = F ;
}
else if (num >= 42 && num <= 44) {
    grade = E;
}
else if (num >= 45 && num <= 59) {
    grade = D;
}
else if (num >= 60 && num <= 69) {
    grade = C;
}
else if (num >= 70 && num <= 79) {
    grade = B;
}
else if (num >= 80 && num <= 89) {
    grade = A;
}
else {
    grade = S;
}
```

and then

```
alertDialog.setMessage("Your Grade is : " + String.valueOf(grade));
```

I think you will get what you want.

Comment: If the number is entered between "0 and 41" in EditText i.e, in et1, it should return integer "0" to n1. Similarly if the number is entered between "42 and 44" it should return "4" and so on.. Hope you understand what i am trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you, But I have another EditText i.e., et2.. How to use same if else Statements for it. I will store the 'grade' values in variables n1, n2..instead of showing in alertbox.

Comment: @VinayKumarG yes you have multiple variables also. I just gave you the idea and what was wrong with your code.